# Cross join databases

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Project: RecipeRolodex

Mission: Create database (Entity Framework, data-first) and ASP.NET MVC5 Application to create and manage catalog of recipes.

Tech: SQL Server 2012, Visual Studio Enterprise 2015

Database diagram - Recipes
https://sqldbm.com/Project/SQLServer/Share/lE7q9CWGgGiR0I-o8mWAAA

My database has been created, the application can read/write data out of it. I'm developing the process to actually create the recipes (the scaffolding isn't sufficient).

I know that the recipes table should contain a foreign key relationship to a UserID in the AspNetUsers table.

I allowed the application to build a new database for ASP.NET Identity.

How would I go about accessing Recipes based off of UserID?

Comment: Should I continue to allow the user/identity data to live in a different database or should I move/recreate it in my recipes database?

Comment: This depends on your use case...Are your users going to be doing things other than being associated with a recipe list?  If not, put them in the same database.  If your user can do other things in your app, say customizing recipe book ui settings, then you may want them to be different because having them in the recipe database may not make sense in the future.  The good news this can change as the scope of your project changes.  Keeping the db string name in a single variable in the app makes this a breeze.  Updating stored procedures might require a little leg work if you move it later, etc

Answer (score 0):

I have had to deal with an issue like this before. I would suggest moving the data to ONE database - really helps with keeping the database relational, which is what makes SQL-server a good database. Also will help with over all speed when dealing with JOINING tables.